# How come that Chrome doesn't render certain sites

Tags: html

I know that this page is pretty messed up code wise (www.tracker.it). But I was wondering the reason why Chrome (and safari btw) completely refuses to render this page (works 100% ie and firefox).

Is it something about nested table or about that javascript poup?

Thank you very much

David

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The page has unclosed divs. Webkit is stricter than Gecko.

In your popupContact div you need to close the form-row divs for username and password.

Eg.

```
<div class="form-row">
<div class="field-label">Username:</div>
<div class="field-widget"><input type="text" name="username"></div>
</div> <!-- This wasn't here -->
<div class="form-row">
<div class="field-label">Password:</div>
<div class="field-widget"><input type="password" name="password"></div>
</div> <!-- nor was this -->
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the site is using invalid HTML.
An easy way to check for this is make use of the [W3 HTML Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) service.

The validator is currently giving 267 errors (http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.tracker.it/&charset=iso-8859-1), as well as reporting character set issues.

Fix the issues and it should render correctly in Chrome and Safari.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's because you're using a VERY old `<area>` and `<map>` tag, and I don't think Webkit (the rendered in Safari and Chrome) handle that tag.

Comment: Is there any kind of docs about what tags are deprecated in Webkit.?

(By the way I want to stress the fact that I DIDN'T make that nightmare of a page)

Comment: This answer is just loaded with awesomeness. Answered by Hanselman and edited by Skeet. Surprised the answer didn't implode...

Comment: What do you mean by "very old"? It is in the latest HTML recommendation http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/objects.html#h-13.6.1 and in the draft of the next version of HTML http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-canvas-element.html#the-map-element

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because Safari and Chrome are using WebKit to render webpage, but FF uses Gecko and IE Trident

Comment: IE doesn't use Gecko. It uses Trident.